how to get global p for categorical variables in quantreg::rq
I am running an analysis for quantile regression evaluated at the median. Below is the code that I have used. My Education level is a 4-level data, giving me 3 p-values. I would like to get an overall or global p-values. I tried anova and gtsummary::add_global_p (which uses car::Anova) but they are not compatible with the rq object. Any advice on how to run this?
qr <- quantreg::rq(Total ~ `Education level`, data = df, tau = 0.5)
summary(qr)

# 95% CI
set.seed(111)
jtools::summ(
  qr,
  confint = TRUE,
  se = "boot", bsmethod = "xy") %>% .$coeftable


I think the issue is that the regression model doesn't have  a defined vcov() method, which is used in most calculations for global p-values . If you do find a solution, please take a moment to post to the gtsummary GitHub page and we can perhaps include it in the package.

You can construct a model without your factor and use anova() to compare models.
library(quantreg)

set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(
  y = c(sapply(c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7), \(mean) rnorm(25, mean))),
  x = rep(letters[1:4], each = 25)
)

qr <- rq(y ~ x, 0.5, data)
summary(qr)
#> Call: rq(formula = y ~ x, tau = 0.5, data = data)
#> 
#> tau: [1] 0.5
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             coefficients lower bd upper bd
#> (Intercept) -0.06271     -0.15849  0.63488
#> xb          -0.19834     -1.04170  0.42398
#> xc           0.54760     -0.21411  0.77643
#> xd           0.85115      0.01330  1.34821

qr0 <- rq(y ~ 1, 0.5, data)
summary(qr0)
#> Call: rq(formula = y ~ 1, tau = 0.5, data = data)
#> 
#> tau: [1] 0.5
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept) 
#>     0.40427

anova(qr, qr0)
#> Quantile Regression Analysis of Deviance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: y ~ x
#> Model 2: y ~ 1
#>   Df Resid Df F value  Pr(>F)  
#> 1  3       96  3.0886 0.03078 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Created on 2024-07-03 with reprex v2.1.0.9000
Reprex files hosted with  on GitHub

I thought of this but I am not sure if they are doing the same thing. My understanding of anova is that it is used to compare the fits of two models; and return whether a more complex model is significantly better at capturing the data than the simpler model. I tried quantile regression qr as above, where x is a binary variable, and got a p-value of 0.085 and when I do the anova with qr0, I got a very different p-value of 0.1308. Why would the p-values be different?
